# How do I directly modify a property of an HTML element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I directly modify a property of an HTML element using jQuery?

Comment: how do you mean a property? an attribute? if so use .attr() ... http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: You cannot modify properties of HTML elements. HTML elements only exist in the static realm of the HTML source code. But you **can** modify properties of DOM element objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  $("selector").attr("attr", "value");
```

[This page describes more](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

To set an arbitrary element attribute value:

```
$("#element-id").attr("attribute-name", "value");
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements have "attributes" and you can edit their values using the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function in jQuery.

`.attr("someAttribute")` returns the value of an attribute.
`.attr("someAttribute", "some value")` sets the value of an attribute.